# SDL_RenderSetViewport strange behaviour

Tags: sdl-2

I don't really understand how to use SDL_RenderSetViewport, or it has a strange behaviour.

`SDL_Rect viewportRect = {-viewportX, viewportY - viewportH + windowH, viewportW, viewportH};
SDL_RenderSetViewport(renderer, &viewportRect);`

This code is the code I use for a window size of (640;480) and a viewport size of something like (windowW * n, windowH * n) for any n.

But, if I change the window size in the code, there's a shift when I display the viewport.

By default, viewportX = viewportY = 0;

I don't understand why the `viewportRect` is so weird, and why it doesn't work when I change window size.

Comment: To clarify, what are the initial values of `y`, `viewportW` and `viewportH`? I ask because it seems like you are trying to invert the y axis.

Comment: y is viewportY, sorry, so initially 0, and viewportW and viewportH are initially windowW and windowH, so 640 and 480.

Comment: Are you sure the viewportH is always equal to windowH? If they are different at some point it would cause a vertical shift. Try to debug them to see if the values are changed.

Comment: No, viewportH is equal to n * windowH, because when I change viewportY, the hidden part of the viewport won't display

Answer (score 0):

For what I know, the SDL does not readjust automatically the windows settings after a resize. Are you handling the `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED`? If not, try to handle it and call `SDL_RenderSetViewport(renderer, &viewportRect)` on it.

Comment: Sorry I edited my post, I change the window size in the code, and not at runtime.